# JavaScript window.onerror and this keyword

Tags: javascript, error-handling, window

I have a problem to get the current object instance on `window.error` event.

If I put this code outside an object method, I can’t get the `obj` parameter, and if I put it inside a `class` method, I can’t get the correct `obj` when is an `instanceOf` of another `class`.

Example:

```
//addTableEvents is a method
addTableEvents: function () {
    var obj = this;
    window.onerror = function (message, url, lineNumber, colNumber, error, obj) {
        var errInfo = {
            INSTANCE: obj.tableId,
            DATE: window.Date(),
            PATH: window.location.href,
            STACKTRACE: error.stack,
            ENV: window.navigator.userAgent,
        };
        console.log(errInfo);
        obj.logError(errInfo);
        return true;
    };
```

If I use, for example:

```
window.onerror = function (message, url, lineNumber, colNumber,error,obj) {
        ...
    };
```

Globally I can’t get the `obj` parameter and needless to say that I need the instance that trows the error. I know the solution is between call, apply or bind but need help on this.

Comment: You should use only once in your app `windo.onerror` as it is global function.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the first scenario you can't "use" *'obj'* because it is also an argument of the function not just a global variable.

(Also there's a missing }; but that just might be a copy/paste typo.)
*Try this:*

```
//addTableEvents is a method
addTableEvents: function () {
    var obj = this;
    window.onerror = function (message, url, lineNumber, colNumber, error) {
        var errInfo = {
            INSTANCE: obj.tableId,
            DATE: window.Date(),
            PATH: window.location.href,
            STACKTRACE: error.stack,
            ENV: window.navigator.userAgent,
        };

        console.log(errInfo);
        obj.logError(errInfo);
        return true;
    };
};
```